# Are the terms Limiting distribution and Stationary distribution properly perceived?

Tags: markov-chains, markov-process

> Consider a Markov chain $(X_n)_n$ on $S=\{1, 2\}$ with initial distribution $α$ and the transition matrix
>
> $P = 
> \begin{bmatrix}  
> 2/3 & 1/3 \\
> 2/3 & 1/3 \\
> \end{bmatrix}$
>
> 1. Limiting distribution = ?
> 2. Stationary distribution = ?

**My Solution:**

$\underline {\text{Limiting Distribution}}$

$P^2 = \begin{bmatrix}  
2/3 & 1/3 \\
2/3 & 1/3 \\
\end{bmatrix} 
\begin{bmatrix}  
2/3 & 1/3 \\
2/3 & 1/3 \\
\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}  
2/3 & 1/3 \\
2/3 & 1/3 \\
\end{bmatrix}$

So, the limiting distribution of $P$ is $P$ itself.

---

$\underline {\text{Stationary Distribution}}$

Let the stationary distribution $\pi = \begin{bmatrix} p & 1-p \end{bmatrix}$.

So,

$\pi P = \pi $

$\Rightarrow \pi (P-1) = 0$

$\Rightarrow \begin{bmatrix} p & 1-p \end{bmatrix} \left(\begin{bmatrix}  
2/3 & 1/3 \\
2/3 & 1/3 \\
\end{bmatrix} - \begin{bmatrix}  
1 & 0 \\
0 & 1 \\
\end{bmatrix}\right) = 0$

$\Rightarrow \begin{bmatrix} p & 1-p \end{bmatrix}  \begin{bmatrix}  
-1/3 & 1/3 \\
2/3 & -2/3 \\
\end{bmatrix} = 0$

$\Rightarrow \begin{bmatrix} \frac{-p}{3}+\frac{2}{3}+\frac{-2p}{3} & \frac{p}{3} + \frac{-2}{3} + \frac{2p}{3} \end{bmatrix}  = 0$

$\Rightarrow p = 2/3$

So,

$\pi = \begin{bmatrix} \frac{2}{3} & \frac{1}{3} \end{bmatrix}$

---

Are the terms *Limiting distribution* and *Stationary distribution* properly perceived in this solution?

Comment: Yes, this is correct.

Comment: @Math1000, Are the terms Limiting distribution and Stationary distribution properly perceived?

Comment: $P$ is not a distribution, so it is certainly not a “limiting distribution.” Also, see https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/48262 for a discussion of the difference between limiting and stationary distributions.